# Newbie help - Domains/Subdomains

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, vps

I have a domain with GoDaddy. I have a VPS with an IP address (and it does not come with a control panel). How do I create domains/subdomains and point them to Default websites and other websites in IIS 7?

Do I need to sign up for Plesk(?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a domain, Godaddy has a tutorial covering this here:

http://help.godaddy.com/article/415

Comment: So, I create a subdomain with godaddy and specify the IP address (?) that it gets forwarded to? If I have multiple subdomains, do I create multiple websites in IIS (with different port numbers?) and then point each of them accordingly?

Comment: When you create a subdomain, it creates a new folder on your root directly with that subdomain. For example, if you create a subdomain TEST, then the folder will be on public_html/TEST. So you would want to forward it to public_html/TEST. The port numbers are all 80. That's the default port number for all browsers. If you use another port number, the browser will not load it unless you explicitly call it like http://example.com::8081(port).

Comment: Ok, I followed the tutorial in the godaddy link. It asks for a http address to forward the subdomain to. I don't have an address to forward to. I need to map the virtual directories i create in Win 2008 to subdomains (hope this makes sense)

Comment: I think the http address is http://yourdomain.com.